# Doctrine: Is it possible to preload child/related N:N entities with single DB query?

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, preload

Given the following parent-child entities, how can I preload all child `C` entities with only single database query when I have many `P` (already loaded) enties?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 **/
class P {
    /** @var Collection @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="C") */
    public $childs;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 **/
class C {
    /** @var int @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
    public $v;
}
```

Test case, this code should not issue any additional database query once preloaded.

```
foreach ($ps as $p) {
    foreach ($p->childs as $child) { $dummy = $child->v; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query preloads all N:N child entities in one query.

note: performance is only about 0.5 times better than foreach over non preloaded data. Probably because the P entity (in my applied case) contained a lot of fields.

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p', 'c')
        ->from(P, 'c')
        ->leftJoin('l.childs', 'c') // preload
        ->where('p.id IN (:ps)')->setParameter('ps', $ps)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```